# How to modify dependency groupId in jitpack.io after publishing 1st version of Android library? [Not solved]

Tags: android, jitpack

I'll explain my problem step by step and also will add more details in case anyone is confused about problem statement.

Scenario:
I wanted to create one simple Hello World kind of Android library just to understand how things works! After doing R&D I've published it on jitpack.io.

Later on, I've mapped with my custom domain as well.
A domain name which I own in Google Domain: jimmytrivedi.in

So, in the Jitpack.io, I can see my dependency as:

```
  dependencies {            
implementation 'in.jimmytrivedi:android.core:Tag'
}
```

This is done. Now I need one more modification.

Problem Statement:
I wanted to rename my dependency groupId to this:

```
   dependencies {
            implementation 'in.jimmytrivedi.android.core:toast:Tag'
}
```

To achieve above modification, I've done 2 changes.
Change1:

```
afterEvaluate {
    publishing {
        publications {
            release(MavenPublication) {
                from components.release

                groupId = 'in.jimmytrivedi.android.core'
                artifactId = 'toast'
                version = '1.0.1'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've done this code change and again published a new release with version: From 1.0.0 to 1.0.1

Change2:
Inside Google Domain - DNS [Note: previously hostname was git.jimmytrivedi.in]

Hostname:
git.android.core.jimmytrivedi.in

Type:
TXT

Value/Data
`https://github.com/jimmytrivedi`

When I'm checking it in Jitpack.io, it is not even taking in.jimmytrivedi, intead it is taking com.github...